# Angular 2 rc1 routerCanDeactivate

Tags: angular

I'm using the `routerCanDeactivate` method of the rc1 router. We have a view where the user searches for items, and when they select one, I want to confirm with them that they want to leave the current route. I can simply do this by:

```
routerCanDeactivate() {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this route');
}
```

A javascript confirm box will pop up, and if the user selects `Yes` they will leave the current route and go on to the next one, or they stay on the current route if they cancel. That works great, and I'm using that in other parts of the app already.

However, what I want to do on one part of the app is only have the confirm show if they are heading towards a specific route. So, for example, let's say I have Dashboard Component, Item Details Component, and the Search Component. When a user searches for items in the search component, and they select an item from the list, they would go to the Items Detail component. But I want to confirm with them before the search component deactivates. However, if they are going to the dashboard, They can freely go there without having to confirm the search component deactivating. To clarify with code, here's what I did in Angular 2 beta.12:

```
routerCanDeactivate(next:ComponentInstruction, prev:ComponentInstruction) {
    if(next.componentType.name.toLowerCase () !== 'details') {
         return confirm('Are you sure you want to go to the details page?');
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I could check the name of the next component, and determine using that if I wanted to show the confirm dialog. In the rc1 router, however, I haven't been able to replicate the same functionality. The `routerCanDeactivate` method in the rc1 router has two optional parameters: `currentTree:RouteTree` and `futureTree:RouteTree`. I've tried to dig through the future tree to see if I can find a usable name, or url or anything, but haven't been able to access what I need. I've seen the name of the component I'm going to if I `console.log` this: `futureTree._root.children[0].value`, and then in the console I expand the `_type` attribute (there's a `name` attribute on `_type`, but you don't seem to be able to access it directly). If I try to access `_type`: `futureTree._root.children[0].value._type`, it logs a function that doesn't help me any either.

If anyone has any ideas how to check what the next component is so I can conditionally show the confirm dialog, that'd be great! I'd love the help!

Thanks!